# Python recursion function parameters issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, subset-sum

I'm calling a function inside itself many times to solve the subset sum problem, using as it called, the recursion solution; anyway, I can't figure out why n (which is the number of elements of the array) value is getting decreasing at first, until it reach 0, which is I get it, but then, after calling it again within itself, it makes n value incremented. Why is that happening, as the whole function doesn't even have an increment contribution for the n value? Where n gets its increasing value from?

**Here is the code:**

```
def printAllSubsetsRec(arr, n, currentSubset, sum):
    # If remaining sum is 0, then print all
    # elements of current subset.

    if (sum == 0):
        i = 0
        sumOfValue = 0
        for value in currentSubset:
            i += 1
            sumOfValue += value
            if (i == len(currentSubset)):
                print(value, " = ", sumOfValue)
            else:
                print(value, end=" + ")
        return True

    # If there are no elements in the array and the sum is not equal to 0.
    if (n == 0 and sum != 0):
        return None


    # I consider two cases for every element:
    # a) Excluding last element.
    # b) Including last element in current subset.
    # -------------------------------------------------

    # Excluding the last element:
    printAllSubsetsRec(arr, n - 1, currentSubset, sum)

    v = [] + currentSubset
    v.append(arr[n - 1])

    # Including the last element:
    printAllSubsetsRec(arr, n - 1, v, sum - arr[n - 1])


#Main:
arr = [10, 7, 5, 18, 12, 20, 15]
sum = 35
n = len(arr)
currentSubset = []
printAllSubsetsRec(arr, n, currentSubset, sum)
```

**The output should be:**

> 18 + 7 + 10  =  35

> 12 + 18 + 5  =  35

> 20 + 5 + 10  =  35

> 15 + 20  =  35

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are seeing the effect of having two recursive calls in the same function.  The first of these gets called, causing n to decrease and building up a stack of recursive calls.  This continues until you hit a return.  At that point the stack unwinds by one level, and now the SECOND recursive call occurs.  The value of "n" increases because there is still a stack of calls holding on to their original "n"s.

Comment: I guess it's just a common nature of recursion, unless recursion structure is linear. Think of a recursion problem to get the number of steps you have to take in order to escape a maze. You are increasing the number of steps in general as you meander in the maze, but once you hit a dead-end, you revert to the previous fork, as if you _decrease_ n. But in fact it is just going back to an original call stack and trying another path (with a decreased n).

Comment: Thank you guys, I get it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignment, and other side effects -

- logical `if` without a corresponding `else`
- mutation and reassignment of `i` and `sumOfValue`
- side effects like `print`

Recursion doesn't have to be difficult or painful. Using functional disciplines we can write `subsets(t,n)` with [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. If the target sum `n` is zero, yield the empty solution
2. (inductive) otherwise `n` is negative or positive. If `n` is negative or the input array `t` is empty, we are out-of-bounds. stop iteration.
3. (inductive) `n` is positive and `t` has at least one element. For all `s` of the subproblem `(t[1:],n-t[0])`, prepend `t[0]` to `s` and yield. *And* yield all results of the subproblem `(t[1:],n)`

```py
def subsets(t, n):
  if n == 0:
    yield ()                              #1
  elif n < 0 or not t:
    return                                #2
  else:
    for s in subsets(t[1:], n - t[0]):    #3
      yield (t[0], *s)
    yield from subsets(t[1:], n)
```

```py
for s in subsets([10, 7, 5, 18, 12, 20, 15], 35):
  print(s)
```

```py
(10, 7, 18)
(10, 5, 20)
(5, 18, 12)
(20, 15)
```

Notice -

- All operations do not mutate or reassign variables
- Side effects like `print` are traded for `yield`
- Caller is free to utilize and transform the results any way desired

To format the results as an mathematical expression -

```py
for s in subsets([10, 7, 5, 18, 12, 20, 15], 35):
  print(" + ".join(map(str, s)), "=", 35)
```

```
10 + 7 + 18 = 35
10 + 5 + 20 = 35
5 + 18 + 12 = 35
20 + 15 = 35
```

To collect all outputs of a generator into a list, use `list` -

```py
print(list(subsets([10, 7, 5, 18, 12, 20, 15], 35)))
```

```py
[(10, 7, 18), (10, 5, 20), (5, 18, 12), (20, 15)]
```

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic! 
It's really professional clean code!
Thank you!